# How to do a checking/condition after ng-change in a dropdown

Tags: angularjs

I have the following drop-down button

```
<select class="input-block-level" ng-model="final_select"
                                ng-options="l.id as l.name group by l.group for l in final_selections['objects']">
                        </select>
```

- Data type of final_selections['objects'] = list of dictionary
- example of one object: `final_selections['objects'][0] = {"id":"A","name":"A: assigned-already","group":"Assign"}`

How can I print a string like "selected A" below the dropdown, once the object A selected? means ng-change triggered and the value A selected then show the message.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like below:

```js
$scope.onChangeSelected = function(item) {
  $scope.finalSelected = item;
}
```

```html
<select class="input-block-level" ng-model="final_select"
  ng-options="l.id as l.name group by l.group for l in final_selections['objects']"
  ng-change="onChangeSelected(finalSelected)">
</select>
<div>
  Selected {{finalSelected.name}}
</div>
```

Comment: getting error -  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: $scope is not defined",

Comment: ya but the value is not printing Narendra

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Narendra, that was a great answer. Update to your answer `ng-change="onChangeSelected(finalSelected)"` to `ng-change="onChangeSelected(finalSelected)"`